# Highlight.js classes being stripped out when blogdown blog is built on Netlify (works locally)

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown, netlify, highlightjs

hopefully someone can help me sort this out! I have a new blogdown blog, using the default theme, that I have succesfully deployed to Netlify. I am using the default Lithium theme.

Highlightjs works when using the 'Serve Site' add-in but does not work on Netlify. Using the inspector I have been able to narrow the problem somewhat:

When inspecting the site in Rstudio this is an example of what I see:

[image: Code block inspected within Rstudio]

When inspecting the same code block from the same source live on Netlify, this is the result:

[image: Code block inspected on Netlify]

As you can see Netlify's build is not building the required class="hljs.something" statements into the generated html

That's as far as I've been able to get on my own so I'm hoping someone has a suggestion!

Comment: If it is relevant info, I am using the latest version of Hugo, 0.30.2, and my HUGO_VERSION environment variable on Netlify is set to that version.

Comment: two suggestions:  1) when you build in our build environment, is it already missing those pieces?  https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/ and 2) if that works, I'd suggest disabling asset optimization as it sounds like a bug in our processing in that case.  For more help beyond that, I'd contact support@netlify.com :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Using Netlify, blogdown, Hugo, etc.

1. I updated my Netlify to use a custom domain, I set the baseURL as `https://my-base-url.com`
2. But I didn't set up HTTPS yet.
3. The site requests to load highlight.js from `https://my-base-url.com/js/highlight.pack.js`
4. Since the `https://` link wasn't active, the **browser thinks it's insecure** and won't load it.
5. So everything looks fine except the highlights
6. the `<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>` statement is there to run the code that makes highlight tags, but the actual code isn't there.

Check the console to see if there are errors loading the .js (instead of a build problem that strips tags after the fact).

Comment: Thanks, just saw this - I don't have a custom domain set up but will investigate the things you mention in the console. Kind of abandoned my blog for awhile but I'm still curious to sort this out.

Comment: @alex.h How did you end up fixing the issue?

Comment: @MatiasAndina lol this irritated me enough at the time that i abandoned the blog